# What to do if you have two training samples with same features but different labels?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I'm curious to know what can be done in the case where two training samples have the same description but different labels. For example, the sample below:

```
`hasFur, hasTwoEyes, hasFourLegs`, `dog`
`hasFur, hasTwoEyes, hasFourLegs`, `cat`
`...other samples`, `labels
```

I think that a model like Naive Bayes wouldn't work too well if there were a few training samples that had matching descriptions with different labels. Would it be better to remove these samples assuming the sample space is enormous? In addition, I read on [Stackoverflow](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40299/can-training-examples-with-almost-the-same-features-but-different-output-cause-m) that SVM could perform better using regularization techniques.

Note: The example is unrealistic but I am using it since I haven't run into any real world cases.